# C# Populate TreeView Recursively Stack Overflow

Tags: c#, recursion, treeview, stack-overflow

Woohoo! I get to post a question about a stack overflow...on stackoverflow :)

So it might just be that it's Friday and my brain is already fried, but I am trying to write a class that recursively populates a given TreeView with a generic type of object that inherits from a TreeNode and a simple interface.

For some reason I am getting a stackoverflow exception when I try to populate the nodes.

My simple interface:

```
public interface ITreeNode
{
    int ItemID { get; set; }
    int ParentID { get; set; }
}
```

Recursion code:

```
public void SetNodes(int rootId)
{
    foreach (T root in _nodeList.Where(i => i.ParentID == rootId))
    {
        _tree.Nodes.Add(root);
        addBrowserItems(root);
    }
}

private void addBrowserItems(T parentNode)
{
    foreach (T child in _nodeList.Where(i => i.ParentID == parentNode.ItemID))
    {
        parentNode.Nodes.Add(child);
        addBrowserItems(child);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Aliostad - reminded me of a song that comment.

Comment: Code looks good to me.  Have you stepped in to make sure your data is ok?

Comment: When your `_nodeList` contains cycles your stack _will_ overflow.

Comment: @Adam If I Lazy-Load the data, it works just fine

Comment: @Henk - Can you elaborate please?

Comment: @Aliostad - My tree only goes 3 deep :)

Comment: Ohhhh - @Henk nailed it.  Your tree has a cycle.  A circular reference.  Node X has a parent, that has a parent, whose parent is X.  Or some similar mind-bending edge case that's creeped into your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so Henk got it, there was a cycle.

I had 2 seperate tables with folder items and report items that were populating the treeview - I was using an identity column as the ID in both - and the identity was duplicated for a folder that had both another folder and report items as children.

I just added a check to only call the recursion for Folder items and it works perfectly now.

I knew it was a silly Friday mistake.

Thanks for the help!